# MapKit - Update MapView to display Moving Annotations via Timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotationview

The end state I'm trying to achieve is to have a running Timer that refreshes a collection of "Vehicle" `annotations`.  The `annotation` `coordinates` are successfully refreshing every 60 seconds using the Timer, but the user must invoke mapView:`regionWillChangeAnimated` and mapView:`regionWillChangeAnimated` delegates.  These delegates are correctly working and moving the Vehicle `annotations`, but I want the `annotations` to move autonomously without having the user interact with the screen.

Here's my approach:

1) Start the Timer.. this works perfectly!

```
//|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
#pragma mark Timers
//|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
dispatch_source_t CreateDispatchTimer(uint64_t interval,
                                   uint64_t leeway, dispatch_queue_t queue, dispatch_block_t block)
{
dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
if (timer)
{
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, interval), interval * NSEC_PER_SEC, (1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC) / 10);
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, block);
    dispatch_resume(timer);
}
return timer;
}

- (void)startTimer
{
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
double secondsToFire = 60.000f;
double secondsLeeway = 2.000f;

_timer = CreateDispatchTimer(secondsToFire, secondsLeeway, queue, ^{
    // Do something
    //Method Call to Refresh NSMutableArray of Vehicle Models
    [self RefreshVehicles];
    NSLog(@"TIMER TASK CALLED");
});
}

- (void)cancelTimer
{
if (_timer) {
    dispatch_source_cancel(_timer);        
    _timer = nil;
    }
}
```

The timer is used to fetch and load the latest Vehicles into an `NSMutable Array` by calling `(void)RefreshVehicles`, this will update the latest `coordinates` for each object that will be used to update the Vehicle `annotation`.  I'm using an `NSNotification` to know when the Async Network Call and `SQLite` work to update the Vehicle records are complete.  When the Notification fires, I'm removing any existing Vehicle `annotations` and then updating the local Vehicle `NSMutable Array`, by calling `addVehiclesToMap` to add the new `annotations` to the Map:

```
//|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
#pragma mark Notification Listener
//|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

- (void)RefreshVehicles:(NSNotification *)notif {

  NSLog(@"++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  Vehicles UPDATED!");

** POST SOLUTION REMARK:  MOVED REMOVE ANNOTATION LOGIC TO: (void)addVehiclesToMap
//** MOVED //If it already Exists, Remove it, Must redraw vehicles because they are moving.
 //** MOVED for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations)
 //** MOVED{
     //** MOVED//Only Remove Vehicles, Leave Stations, they are static
     //** MOVED if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[VehicleAnnotation class]])
     //** MOVED{
        //** MOVED [self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
     //** MOVED}
 //** MOVED}

//Load Vehicle Collection
self.vehicleCollection = [[VehicleModelDataController defaultVehicleModelDataController] vehicleReturnAll];    

[self addVehiclesToMap];

}
```

Here's the Method for `addVehiclesToMap`: 
**POST SOLUTION REMARK: After implementing Anna's solution to update the map `annotations` on the `Main Thread`, I started to receive the following error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x16d94af0> was mutated while being enumerated.`'

This is because I was removing the annotations from the timer refresh on a background thread.  To fix this issue, I implemented `[self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];` to the Main Thread as well.**

```
/*
 ----- VEHICLES -----
 */
- (void)addVehiclesToMap {

//If it already Exists, Remove it, Must redraw vehicles because they are moving.
for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations)
{
    //Only Remove Vehicles, Leave Stations, they are static
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[VehicleAnnotation class]])
    {
        //Remove Vehicle Annotation to MapView on the Main Thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
        });
    }
}

//Loop through Vehicle Collection and generate annotation for each Vehicle Object
for (VehicleModel *vehicle in vehicleCollection) {

    //New Vehicle Annotation Instance
    VehicleAnnotation *myVehicleAnnotation = [[VehicleAnnotation alloc] init];

    myVehicleAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([vehicle.vehicleLat doubleValue], [vehicle.vehicleLon doubleValue]);  
    myVehicleAnnotation.vehicleId = [vehicle.vehicleId stringValue];                
    myVehicleAnnotation.title = vehicle.vehicleLabel;                               
    myVehicleAnnotation.subtitle = vehicle.vehicleIsTrainDelayed;                   

    **POST SOLUTION REMARK: PER ANNA'S SOLUTION, MOVE addAnnodation TO MAIN THREAD:**
    //MODIFIED THIS:** [self.mapView addAnnotation:myVehicleAnnotation];

    **//TO THIS:**
    //Add Vehicle Annotation to MapView on the Main Thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self.mapView addAnnotation:myVehicleAnnotation];
    });**
}
```

}

Next the code for `viewAnnotation` Delegate:

```
//|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
#pragma mark MKAnnotationView Delegate
//|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id     <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    // if it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;


// handle our two custom annotations
//
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[VehicleAnnotation class]]) /// for Vehicles Only
 {

     //Important, can't use annotation, this lets the compiler know that the annotation is actually an StationAnnotation object.
     VehicleAnnotation *vehicleAnnotation = (VehicleAnnotation *)annotation;

     //Reuse existing Annotation
     NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = vehicleAnnotation.vehicleId.lowercaseString;
     MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

    if (!pinView)
    {

        //Set unique annotation identifier  exp: 304 (The Vehicles's Unique Number)
        NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = vehicleAnnotation.vehicleId.lowercaseString;


        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;


        NSString *vehicleFlagIcon = [@"map_train_green_" stringByAppendingString:vehicleAnnotation.vehicleId.lowercaseString];
        UIImage *flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:vehicleFlagIcon];

        CGRect resizeRect;

        resizeRect.size = flagImage.size;
        CGSize maxSize = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds,
                                     [VehicleMapViewController annotationPadding],
                                     [VehicleMapViewController calloutHeight]).size;

        maxSize.height -= self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [VehicleMapViewController calloutHeight];
        if (resizeRect.size.width > maxSize.width)
            resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(maxSize.width, resizeRect.size.height / resizeRect.size.width * maxSize.width);
        if (resizeRect.size.height > maxSize.height)
            resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(resizeRect.size.width / resizeRect.size.height * maxSize.height, maxSize.height);

        resizeRect.origin = (CGPoint){0.0f, 0.0f};
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resizeRect.size);
        [flagImage drawInRect:resizeRect];
        UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        annotationView.image = resizedImage;
        annotationView.opaque = NO;

        NSString *vehicleLogo = [@"map_train_green_" stringByAppendingString:vehicleAnnotation.vehicleId.lowercaseString];
        UIImageView *sfIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:vehicleLogo]];
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = sfIconView;

        return annotationView;

    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
}    

return nil;
}
```

Next I do have logic to remove then re-add the `annotations` using the following delegates.  These delegates work just fine, but require the user to interact with the screen.  I'm trying to refresh the Map every X seconds instead.  So far to see any changes to the `annotation` locations, I must touch the screen and move the map to invoke these deletes.  I'm still unable to watch the vehicles move autonomously without having to perform interaction.

**POST SOLUTION REMARKS: I REMOVED THESE DELEGATES BECAUSE THEY WERE PERFORMING UN-NECESSARY UPDATES TO THE VEHICLE ANNOTATION MAKING THE ICONS FLICKER WHEN THE MAP WAS TOUCHED AND MOVED... LETTING THE TIMER DO THE WORK**

```
**// DELETED** -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated { ...Annotation tear down and rebuild code here }
**//DELETED** -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation { ...Annotation tear down and rebuild code here }
```

**Am I even close to a solution here?  Thanks in advance...**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling the `addAnnotation` on the main thread so the UI updates without that delay:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:myVehicleAnnotation];
});
```

*An unrelated suggestion:*
Instead of removing and re-adding the vehicle annotations, you could simply update the `coordinate` properties of the existing vehicles and the map view will automatically move the annotation views.  This can result in a slightly smoother effect though it's slightly harder to implement the logic (eg. you'll need to find the existing vehicle annotation in the map view `annotations` array and update it instead of creating a new `VehicleAnnotation`).  You also have to account for new vehicles and deleting annotations for vehicles that no longer exist.

*Another unrelated suggestion:*
Instead of this roundabout and cryptic way to set the coordinate:

```
NSString *coord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%@,%@}", 
   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", vehicle.vehicleLat], 
   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", vehicle.vehicleLon]];
CGPoint point = CGPointFromString(coord);
myVehicleAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point.x, point.y);
```

I suggest this more direct and less cryptic approach:

```
myVehicleAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
    [vehicle.vehicleLat doubleValue], [vehicle.vehicleLon doubleValue]);
```

Comment: +1 Anna! Thanks so much, I've updated my question to reflect the changes suggested; in addition, to moving [self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation]; onto the main thread to avoid a nasty mutated Array exception.

This is a great starter, and like the idea of maintaining 2 sets of vehicle collections to track Actual and Past locations, then updating/removing/adding instead of tearing down and rebuilding the annotations.

However, this solution is optimal, the Map is responsive and the UI glides with interaction so I may not have to refactor the solution.

Comment: UPDATE:  I ended up re-writing addVehiclesToMap to check for ADD/DELETE/UPDATE for annotations.  Primary reason is the annotation's annotationView.canShowCallout = YES became an issue when the annotation was deleted and added.  If the user had the annotation call out displayed, it would disappear when the annotation coord was deleted/re-added... not a great user experience IMO.